# How can you perform other functions simultaneously with PlaySound?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a C++ Windows Application program which needs to Play a randomly chosen song from an array and the user needs to be able to play another song on the list at the click of a button. How would you stop the sound from the first song as to play the second song?

By pressing my button which plays the first song, the audio resource is played, however my program no longer responds to any clicks and the code does not continue until the song is complete. I have attempted using CreateThread(), however to no avail as my program remains in an unresponsive state.

The Function containing PlaySound:

```
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE WINAPI PlayWavFile(int resource) {
    PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(resource), hInst, SND_RESOURCE | SND_SYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

The case in the WndProc function which determines the result of button presses:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
            HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                PlayWavFile(i),
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL
            );
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
            HANDLE hPlaySecond = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                PlayWavFile(j),
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL
            );
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3) {
            HANDLE hStop = CreateThread(
                NULL,
                0,
                PlayWavFile(NULL),
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL
            );
        }
        break;
```

Also if if I try clicking my button which should give the wParam value of 3, the program reaches an exception which states:

Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Audio Player.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000. occurred.

The end goal is that the program would just be responsive whilst the music plays in the background.

Comment: Unrelated to the base issue, but definitely related to your solution attempts, you're leaking the thread handle with each thread created. If you're not planning on waiting on the thread via waitforsingleobject or similar, you should closehandle the thread handle returned from CreateThread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `PlaySound` directly with `SND_ASYNC` instead of `SND_SYNC`. That would cause `PlaySound` to return immediately and play the sound in the background.

There's no need to mess around with threads for that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked straight away. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
    NULL,
    0,
    PlayWavFile(i),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

you are ***calling*** the function `PlayWavFile`, and are using the value it returns as the thread function to call. And since the function is always returning `0`, which is a null pointer, it's equivalent to

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
    NULL,
    0,
    nullptr,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

The thread function arguments is of the type [`LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/lpthread-start-routine-function-pointer), which is a pointer to a function which takes an `LPVOID` argument, and returns a `DWORD`.

You need to change your thread function accordingly, and then call [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) as

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(
    NULL,
    0,
    &PlayWavFile,  // Pass a pointer to the function
    reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(i),    // The argument to pass
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

With this the `PlayWavFile` could look something like

```
DWORD PlayWavFile(LPVOID argument) {
    int resource = reinterpret_cast<int>(argument);
    PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(resource), hInst, SND_RESOURCE | SND_SYNC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and received this error: argument of type "DWORD (*)(LPVOID arg)" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE"

Comment: @Siggers `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` is the function pointer type for a thread proc. It's *not* the proper return value type for a thread-proc as you seem to be using it. Your function should (a) return a `DWORD`, (b) use the `WINAPI` calling convention, and (c) take a single `LPVOID` argument. And heed what I said about the leaking thread handle in the general comments below your question; it's important.